# Scale imageview to fit background width

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I'm having trouble to make my `ImageView` fit the background width

see :

[image]

here is the xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/bg"
   android:paddingLeft="8dp" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/actualites"
        android:onClick="onClickactu"
        android:text="Actualités"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:background="@null"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/agenda"
        android:text="Agenda"
        android:onClick="onClickagend"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@null" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/municipalite"
        android:onClick="onClickmuni"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:text="Municipalité"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:background="@null" />

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/jeunesse"
            android:text="Jeunesse"
            android:onClick="onClickjeun"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/sante"
            android:onClick="onClicksant"
            android:text="Santé"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/action_sociale"
            android:text="Action Sociale"
            android:onClick="onClicksoci"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/commerces"
            android:text="Commerces"
            android:onClick="onClickcomm"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/associations"
            android:text="Associations"
            android:onClick="onClickasso"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/cadre_vie"
            android:text="Cadre de vie"
            android:onClick="onClickvie"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ville_daudaces" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fillXY"
        android:src="@drawable/barand" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: There's no XML. Have you set the ImageView to match_parent in width? Don't have any padding or margins that you've forgotten about?

Comment: tried<match_parent, same issues, no margin or padding are set

Comment: yep just checked first one, done ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the padding in the parent `RelativeLayout` ie `android:paddingLeft="8dp"`.Remove this line

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `android:layout_width` from `wrap_content` to `match_parent` as below

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

As **goonerdroid** said, remove the `android:paddingLeft` attribute from parent `RelativeLayout` or set it to `0dip`...this `android:paddingLeft="8dp"` causing the extra space to the left of `ImageView`.

Comment: can you post your full layout xml file?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `android:scaleType` value by `fillXY`?

Comment: i've edited first post with the full xml layout, tried fitxy aswell, no success

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:  `android:paddingLeft="8dp"`

Like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bg">
```